# Использование Blur эффекта для определенного слоя

Tags: unity3d

Добрый день, есть две картинки. Одна расположена на слое 1. Вторая на слое 2. Так же есть две камеры, на одной из них висит Blur optimized effect. Как сделать что бы к первой картинки применялся Blur Effect, а к второй нет? При помощи "Culling Mask" делал что бы камера с Blur effect отображала только слой с первой картинкой, а вторая камера отображала слой с второй картинкой. Но ничего не получилось в чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мы делали так, у нас было несколько камер, каждая из которых отрисовывала свой слой с залитым прозрачным задним фоном в `RenderTexture`. Затем мы их постэффектом сливали в одну итоговую камеру. При этом на каждой камере мог использоваться свой эффект и они не пересекались.

Если у вас сейчас на первом слое рисуется картинка, потом на втором вы хотите отрисовать второй слой и наложить его с блуром поверх первого, то фактически ваша вторая камера скорей всего рисует поверх картинки с камеры 1, и эффект размытия накладывается на итоговое изображение.

Ну и как другой вариант можно попробовать нарисовать в отдельной камере маску с требуемого слоя в `RenderTexture` и потом отрисовать через свой вариант `Blur` все. Правда идей как быть с глубиной и тем что одни объекты другие закрывают предложить не могу. Мы у себя рисовали космос, и  у нас были разные эффекты для космоса и космической станции, и были постэффекты на общей камере где картинки смешивались.